# Conflicts between java.net.URL and java.net.URI when dealing with hostname contains underscore( ), is it a bug?

Tags: java, url

Someone has submiited a bug to JDK, saying that hostname contains underscore(_) is not valid url.
The following was the response.  [reference link](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8132508)

> RFC 952 disallows _ underscores in hostnames. So, this is not a bug. I also haven't been able to find examples of actual usage.
>   So, unless a particularly compelling case can be made, I'm closing as not a bug.

I am wondering, if hostname with underscore is not valid, **why the result is differrent between java.net.URI and java.net.URL**? Is it **a bug** or a feature? 
Here is the example.

```
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://test_1.tanglei.name");
System.out.println(url.getHost()); //test_1.tanglei.name
java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI("http://test_1.tanglei.name");
System.out.println(uri.getHost()); //null
```

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170265

Comment: Found that the bug was submitted by myself, However I have not received any response after I submitted the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a bug or a feature?

I don't think the reviewer entirely understood that you were talking about 3-way inconsistency between two different URI constructors and the 4 arg URL constructor.  (Your bug report does not spell out precisely which of the inconsistencies is concerning you.)  He has viewed it as a report as a 2-way inconsistency between URL and URI.

The review is somewhat terse, but the reviewer's point is the URL constructor is behaving *in accordance with its specification*.  Since the specification explicitly states that no validation is performed, this is not a bug in the code.  This is indisputable.

What he didn't spell out is that fixing this inconsistency (by changing the URL class specification) would break lots of peoples' 20+ year old code Java code.  That would be a really bad idea.  It can't happen.

So ... this inconsistency is a "feature".